# how to retrieve objects from NSArray by their tags in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

I'm using an NSArray of images, and each image has a tag. I want to know how to retrieve these images from the array using their tags.

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you include the Class declaration for the objects held by NSArray?

Comment: What do you mean my the word "tag"?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromArray:(NSArray *)array withTag:(NSInteger)tag {
  for (UIImage *image in array) {
    if ([image tag] == tag)
      return image;
  }
  return nil;
}
```

Completely untested, though.

Comment: `UIImage` does not have a `tag` property or method. `UIImageView` does. Unfortunately, the question is not specific enough.

Comment: The OP didn't say the the image objects were UIImages or UIImageViews.  But a subclass of UIImage with an added tag property might work using the above code.